# make glibc-2.20 report xxx/nscd/selinux.c:368: undefined reference to `security_deny_unknown

Tags: security, pthreads, glibc, selinux

my os is: RedHat5.8,

kernel is: Linux hcw3 2.6.18-308.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 17:21:15 EST 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

I have installed pyqt5 by install Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86.sh in my host, but I got a seriese of error when run a simple 'hellworld.py' program. after one by one install releated packages, finally there is still a dependency package libpthread.so.0 require to install version `GLIBC_2.20'.  but my server only glibc2.5 installed, so I need to install another newer glibc in other place to be called by libpthread.so.0.

I download glibc2.20 source code, and configure command is shown in below:

```
    ../configure --prefix=/app/open_source/glibc/2.20 --with-headers=/usr/include
```

is ok, but I got the following error when run  'make'

```
    /app/open_source/glibc/glibc-2.20/build/nscd/nscd.o: In function `main':
    /app/open_source/glibc/glibc-2.20/nscd/nscd.c:297: warning: inotify_init1 is not implemented and will always fail
    /app/open_source/glibc/glibc-2.20/build/nscd/selinux.o: In function `nscd_request_avc_has_perm':
    /app/open_source/glibc/glibc-2.20/nscd/selinux.c:368: undefined reference to `security_deny_unknown'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The part of selinux.c is shown in below:

```
    /* Check the permission from the caller (via getpeercon) to nscd.
   Returns 0 if access is allowed, 1 if denied, and -1 on error.

   The SELinux policy, enablement, and permission bits are all dynamic and the
   caching done by glibc is not entirely correct.  This nscd support should be
   rewritten to use selinux_check_permission.  A rewrite is risky though and
   requires some refactoring.  Currently we use symbolic mappings instead of
   compile time constants (which SELinux upstream says are going away), and we
   use security_deny_unknown to determine what to do if selinux-policy* doesn't
   have a definition for the the permission or object class we are looking
   up.  */
int
nscd_request_avc_has_perm (int fd, request_type req)
{
  /* Initialize to NULL so we know what to free in case of failure.  */
  security_context_t scon = NULL;
  security_context_t tcon = NULL;
  security_id_t ssid = NULL;
  security_id_t tsid = NULL;
  int rc = -1;
  security_class_t sc_nscd;
  access_vector_t perm;
  int avc_deny_unknown;

  /* Check if SELinux denys or allows unknown object classes
     and permissions.  It is 0 if they are allowed, 1 if they
     are not allowed and -1 on error.  */
  if ((avc_deny_unknown = security_deny_unknown ()) == -1)
    dbg_log (_("Error querying policy for undefined object classes "
           "or permissions."));
```

How to fixed it? Could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could compile glibc without SELinux support (configure with `--disable-selinux`).

I'm surprised you actually got that far.  glibc 2.20 needs a kernel version of at least 2.6.32.  Maybe you can still build the library because the Red Hat kernel backports added all the necessary system interfaces, but you won't be able to run any programs linked against this glibc on a 2.6.18 kernel because of the version check built into glibc binaries.

Instead, you will have to port PyQt and Anaconda to your Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.8 system.  You can get a more modern C++ compiler through Developer Toolset (DTS), but even then, it will be quite a bit of work.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion. I will have a try your proposal